# PHP urldecode all $_GET and $_POST values

Tags: php, urldecode

I have a REST web service written in PHP.

Is there an easy function which will clean all the values of a $_POST and $_GET using urldecode() so I need to do it for each variable in each function alone?

Comment: Use a `foreach` loop.

Comment: urldecode converts the values to their original form because they were urlencoded when posted, therefore, no need to do this.

Comment: You shouldn't need this, if you need to decode _again_, you have encoded them _twice_ somewhere, I'd fix it there.

Comment: the $_POST and $_GET are already urldecoded ??